# Understand why suggested edit was rejected so as to learn

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Just had a suggested edit rejected on this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/267305/105480) and I can't seem to understand why the reason provided is valid. Perhaps, if the reviewer [toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) (one of our community moderators) who took the action or any other one who could explain the logic so as to educates me, that will be great.

The reason cited by the reviewer was: `This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.`

My edit was to add [backbone](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backbone) as a tag to the post for the sake of it's relevance.

The author did not, but in analyzing and answering the OP, it is clear that the challenge the author faced relates to the way he/she was using *Backbone.js*.

Even though I see nothing wrong with my action based on the community rules and motives for edits, I stand to be corrected if wrong so as to understand what I might have gotten wrong, otherwise, my edit accepted.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My fault. Sorry! I have seen that it was tag-only edit, and usually we expect a little bit more from a suggested edit.

But … the post is good otherwise, there isn't anything else that needs improvement, so I misjudged this case. Please try again, and thank you for your patience. :)